# Bootstrapped data to fit models and comparison

Tags: modeling, inference, bootstrap, boosting

I have a large data set, say 40k row by 60 columns.

Now I do bootstrapping (resample the rows with replacement) on this whole data set for 10k times. Then I used each of the 10k data sets to fit a XGboost model -- so I have 10k XGboost models.

Also, I fit another XGboost model only using the original data set.

Now for the 10k models I generated from bootstrapping, I have a row of test data, then I can get a distribution of predictions from the 10k models. I also get a prediction using the same test data from the model I fitted using the original data (without bootstrapping and replacement).

So will the mean of the 10k predictions VERY close to the prediction from the single XGboost model fitted using the original data?

(I use the same predictors and labels from my data set in all the XGboost models.)

Any comment and references are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

From what is described it appears you have computed some bootstrap prediction intervals through the "bootstrap pairs" procedure; "bootstrap residuals" procedures are more common but what you did is perfectly fine too (albeit more expensive). I think that looking into a reference like  Khosravi et al. (2011) [*Comprehensive Review of Neural Network-Based Prediction Intervals and New Advances*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5966350) will be very helpful. The author explore a number of different ways to get prediction intervals from core ML algorithms (Delta, Mean-Variance Estimation, Bayesian and Bootstrap Methods).

Finally to answer your side question directly: Yes, the mean value of those 10K estimates will be very close to the prediction of the single XGBoost model.